# Unable to execute cypher statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, neo4jclient

I am using VS 2013 and the Neo4j client in an MVC application and can't get past building the query.

In the following code, I can connect to my server but on the `var newUser` line I get an error over the `new User` statement saying it's a property but used like a type, that can bee seen in this screen shot:

[image: screeny]

```
var client = new GraphClient(new System.Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();

var newUser = new User { Id = 456, Name = "Jim" };
client.Cypher
    .Merge("(user:User { Id: {id} })")
    .OnCreate("user")
    .Set("user = {newUser}")
    .WithParams(new
    {
        id = newUser.Id,
        newUser
    })
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I think I need to add or remove a reference but I a not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error, you'll see `User` is a property of `Controller`, so it's not recognized as a type.

You'll need to prefix the namespace, like `new Neo4j.User()` or whatever its documentation states it uses.

Comment: AH, I found I needed to create that user class so I did and gave it a different name.

Comment: @Baub now I actually read the code, you don't have to do that. You can just remove `User` (so `var newUser = new { Id = ...}`), or remove the entire `var newUser` line (along with your class) and just enter the values in the `.WithParams()` call.

Comment: I can't seem to find any examples, or figure out how to make it work, where I can somehow store the result of a query into a variable in VS to test.  For example, I want to see if something exists and based on that result, do something.  Obviously I can't do that with .ExecuteWithoutResults.  Can't seem to find a decent reference to the class, all docs I have found don't seems to be detailed enough.

Comment: @Baub that is pretty Neo4j-specific, so I'm afraid I can't help with that.